# Pillow draw text on image - clear between iterations Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I've got an image as template and I want to write on it several different names from a list.

```
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(path)

for name in list:

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(loaded_image)

    draw.text(text)
    
    image.save(my_path)
```

The problem is that the text drawn on saved images keeps remaining, even if they should be different references. Does anyone know how to make each image with its own text?

Is there any CLEAR method for the image itself? To run between drawings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a fresh copy of the original each time before you write on it, like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Open the image
im = Image.open('image.png')

# Make a list of the annotation texts
words = ['the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']

# Iterate over all annotations
for word in words:
    # Take a clean copy of original image - the following line is the actual answer
    clear = im.copy()

    # Draw the text on the clean copy and save
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(clear)
    draw.text((10,10), word)
    clear.save(word + '.png')
```

Comment: Works. Looks like my problem when using this approach was because I was using a global instance instead of the copy itself. Thanks!